# How to clone one database to another?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, rubygems

I want to clone one database to another in MongoDB using '[mongo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver)' gem.

I can do it in MongoDB console like this:

```
db.copyDatabase(fromdb, todb, fromhost, username, password)
```

So, is there any way to do this using that gem?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
@connection = Mongo::MongoClient.new
@connection.copy_database('from', 'to')
=> {"ok"=>1.0}
```